# How to create Threads using the same Struct in C

Tags: c, multithreading, struct

I need to create N threads using the very same structure and also using a function so the structure changes the value of the parameters.

The structure i'm trying to use is this one:

```
    struct people{
  int id;
  int attend;
  int claim;
  int leave;
  pthread_t thread;
};
```

The function that i'm trying to use is this one:

```
void execThr(){
struct people p;
p.id=0;
p.attend=1;
p.claim=0;
p.leave=0;
}
```

And, finally, the main would be:

```
int main( {
pthread_create(&thread,NULL,execThr,&p);
}
```

My question is, is that correct? If it isn't, how could I create N threads (using some kind of "for loop") using the same struct and modifying it for each thread.

Thank you so much.

Comment: This is wrong on several accounts. First the issue pointed out by unwind, second you do not join/wait for threads (this will likely crash or give incoherent results), and third it does not make any sense at all to spawn a thread for processing such a small amount of data.

Comment: spawning a thread and then exiting the program makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

You'll better have an array of `struct people` , e.g.

```
#define NBPEOPLE 5
struct people guytab[NBPEOPLE];
memset (&guytab, 0, sizeof(guytab));
for (int i=0; i<NBPEOPLE; i++)
   pthread_create(&guytab[i].thread, NULL, execThr, guytab+i);
```

Then

```
void execThr(void*data) {
 struct people *thisguy = data;
 // do something with thisguy
}
```

Read some [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).

You will need some [synchronization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization) to avoid [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not correct. By defining the struct instance inside the thread function, it's local to each thread function's stack. Your reference to `p`, a local variable inside a different function, from `main()` will not compile.

Try:

```
void execThr(void *args)
{
  struct people *p = args;
  p->id=0;
  p->attend=1;
  p->claim=0;
  p->leave=0;
}

int main(void)
{
 struct people p;

 pthread_create(&thread, NULL, execThr, &p);

 return 0;
}
```

Of course, sharing a datastructure between threads requires lots of thought to synchronization and so on.